# pandas - a better way to plot binned x vs y

Tags: python, pandas

New to Pandas and I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish the following -

Set up:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 1, .01)
y = np.random.binomial(10, x, 100)
bins = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
print(df.head())

    x  y
0  -1  1
1  38  1
2  56  0
3  42  0
4  41  0
```

I would like to group the x values into equal size bins, and for each bin take the average value of both x and y.

```
my_bins = pd.cut(x, bins=20)
data = df[['x', 'y']].groupby(my_bins).agg(['mean', 'size'])
print(data.head())
                        x                y       
                     mean   size      mean   size
age                                              
(-1.101, 4.05]  -1.000000  87990  0.768428  87990
(4.05, 9.1]           NaN      0       NaN      0
(9.1, 14.15]          NaN      0       NaN      0
(14.15, 19.2]   18.512286   1872  0.493590   1872
(19.2, 24.25]   22.768022   8906  0.496968   8906
```

Well that works.  But from here, how do I plot x's mean vs y's mean?  I know I can do something like

```
data.columns = data.columns.droplevel() # remove the multiple levels that were created
data.columns = ['x_mean', 'x_size', 'y_mean', 'y_size'] # manually set new column names
data.plot.scatter(x='x_mean', y='y_mean') # plot
```

But this feels wrong and clunky as I have to drop the column levels (which removes useful structure from my data) and I have to manually rename the columns.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the x and y parameters pointing the multi-level columns using tuples:

```
data.plot.scatter(x=('x', 'mean'), y=('y', 'mean'))
```

This way, you don't need to rename the columns in order to plot it.